# Facebook App request Push Notifications for iOS App not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am developing an iOS App in Unity and is using App request to send gifts. App requests are working fine but I dont get any push notifications from iOS Facebook App. My Facebook App is in Live Mode with bundle Id, iPhone Store Id, iPad Store Id set in Facebook App Settings.

What should I do so that push notifications show up whenever, app request is received?

Comment: Did you check sending the request from an iOS device, to another fb user who has an ios device also, with fb app installed?

Comment: Yes, notification does not show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a [Bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/682257341884385) to facebook and they were able to produce it. They have merged my bug report with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1622259721322236) one. Hopefully, they will fix it in a future update.